# HTML5 and Jquery - Data transfer from one page to another page

Tags: jquery, html, windows-phone-8

I am creating a window phone 8 apps using HTML5 and jquery. I have two html page, first page has some input box and a button and second page has control on which I have to display input data of first page. On clicking on first page button it navigate to second page through  `window.location.href = "xyz.html";`.

How can I pass data from first page so can will get on second page using javascript/jquery.

I have try to send using query-sting like `window.location.href = "xyz.html?x=value"` but this is not accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I think this sample code will help you.

`<input type="script" value="" name= "" id="myInput"/>
<input type="button" value="nextPage" onclick="nextPage();">`

`<script type="text/javascript">
     function nextPage(){
     //get the input value of the field 
    var inputValue= $('#myInput').val ;`

```
`  //jump to next page
  location.href= 'nextpage.html' +inputValue ;
}
```

`